# How to check the File Type in java

Tags: java, file-type

How can I check whether the file version is `.gz` or `.bzip2`. I searched in File Java docs but couldn' find any method. Can you please let me know?

My requirement is to show the file on the UI , if .txt doesn't exist then check if .gz exists and if that doesnt exist then check if .bzip2 file exists and hence I am looking to check the extension of the file. I am assuming that I need to be looking at the Type of file.

Comment: just look at what characters come after the last dot in the the file's name. that's the only thing that determines file type.

Comment: You will probably need a supporting library capable of reading those file formats.  I suggest you start googling...

Comment: you're asking two different things, so which are you really interested in: the file extension to tell you "what kind of file it is" (which can be a blatant lie, because a .jpg file could actually be a php script named .jpg), or the actual file type based on the data in the file (which requires opening the file, looking at the byte layout, and matching it against known layouts)

Comment: I want to do some processing based on what kind of a file it is

Comment: right, but what do you mean with that. Do you mean "assume a .txt file is a text file and a .jpg file is an image" (fast, not necessarily reliable), or do you want to actually completely ignore the file and automatically check what it is based on the data inside the file? (more reliable, but much slower, and uses way more cpu and memory)

Comment: Assume a .txt file as text file and .jpg as jpeg file

Comment: My requirement is to show a file on the UI , if .txt doesn't exist then check if .gz exists and if that doesnt exist then check if .bzip2 file exists and hence I am looking to check the extension of the file. I am assuming that I need to be looking at the Type of file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use [Files](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html) Utility of **[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)** , and use the method of `Files.getFileExtension(String String fullName)`

```
System.out.println(Files.getFileExtension("C:\\fileName.txt"));
```

The output is:

```
txt
```

The source code is pretty simple though,

```
public static String getFileExtension(String fullName) {
    checkNotNull(fullName);
    String fileName = new File(fullName).getName();
    int dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
    return (dotIndex == -1) ? "" : fileName.substring(dotIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: This will detect the extension, but not the file type. As extension is optional in linux, this may not always work.

Answer (score 9):

You could use:

- [java.io.File.getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) to get the filename and then apply a regular expression
- [java.nio.file.Files.probeContentType()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29)
- [org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getExtension()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, this appears to be a Stack Overflow bug!

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
String extension = "";
int i = fileName.lastIndexOf('.');
if (i >= 0) { extension = fileName.substring(i+1); }
```

which would produce the extension not including the "." so Notepad.txt this syntax would produce txt --- Or word.docx this syntax would produce docx

Comment: I don't think that the OP has any trouble parsing the String as nothing in his question seems to indicate this.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 provides [`FileTypeDetector#probeContentType(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29) which returns

> [...] the string form of the value of a Multipurpose Internet Mail
>   Extension (MIME) content type as defined by RFC 2045: Multipurpose
>   Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) Part One: Format of Internet Message
>   Bodies. The string must be parsable according to the grammar in the
>   RFC 2045.

If that fails, you don't have many options. You can check the extension (unsafe because a file can have any name) or try to parse it as gz or bzip2 content and whichever succeeds is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically determining the type of a file can be surprisingly tricky and there have been many content-based file identification approaches proposed and implemented. There are several implementations available in Java for detecting file types and most of them are largely or solely based on files' extensions

Here is [LINK](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/02/determining-file-types-in-java.html)